# Need for a side book for E. Soper's Classical Theory Of Fields

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, field-theory, classical-field-theory

I am reading now E. Soper, *Classical Theory Of Fields,* now and sometimes it is very hard to follow the equations. So I need a side book on [classical field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_field_theory) to read it comfortably. Landau & Lifshitz's book is not helping as its content and topics are very much different.

Answer (score 8):

The classical reference is Landau & Lifshitz, **[The Classical Theory of Fields](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750627689)**, from the Course of Theoretical Physics. As all Landau & Lifshitz books, masterpieces [in my opinion] full of content but sometimes a little difficult to grasp for beginners.

Comment: Could you recommend an introductory classical field textbook to me ?

Answer (score 1):

Along with Landau and Lifshitz, there are books which although not explicitly about classical field theory, have good treatments. Chapters 11 and 12 of [Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047130932X) are about special relativity and field theory, and I would  recommend [Goldstein's Classical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8177582836) as an introduction, where field theory is introduced in some of the later chapters.