# Resources on Classical Field Theory

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, resource-recommendations, education, classical-field-theory

I have not been able to find where to ask this question on Stack Exchange; so pardon me if this is inappropriate and kindly redirect me:

How may I obtain a referral to texts that cover classical field theory?   I am aware of only one, by Lev Landau, written decades ago.   I do not have access to a major library's or university's catalog.

Comment: http://www.wiese.itp.unibe.ch/lectures/classical.pdf , check this out

Comment: there are these collected in a link here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45941/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691606/2451 and links therein.