# Literature Suggestions - Classical Field Theory

Tags: field-theory, resource-recommendations, education, classical-field-theory

I'm a physics graduate that is joining the master degree program of my University. One of the areas of research that i'm very interested is Quantum Field Theory over curved surfaces, but the point is that i don't know how to begin to start studying these subjects. I imagine that i should star from classical field theory and go all through until reach in the quantum field theory over curved spaces. So, do you have suggestions of literature to start those subjects?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45941/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/691606/2451 and links therein.